# Find the such way that maximum distance of a jump in the way is possible minimal

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming, greedy

There are a platforms that can be placed on different heights. For example, these map shows how platforms have been placed (in the program it is presented as matrix `NxM, |N|, |M| <= 100`

```
      _ _ _    
    D _   _ _  
            _ _
              _
    S _ _ _ _ _
```

In this map `space` means `space`, `_` - platform, `S` - the platform where we start from, `D` - destination point. The monster that walks on this map can **jump up, down** or **move to the left or to the right**.
The possible way to reach `D` from `S` by monster is:

```
  + + +    
D +   + +  
        + +
          +
S + + + + +
```

or it may reach the `D` in this way:

```
      _ _ _    
    D _   _ _  
    +       _ _
    +         _
    S _ _ _ _ _
```

So, combinations of reaching destination point can be varied in many ways but the main point is that in the first case the maximum *distance* of a jump that is made by monster is `1`, because the maximum distance between two platforms in this way is `1`. In the second case monster has reached destination very quickly but he made the jump of distance `2`. The main goal of the monster is to reach the destination point and not make big jumps (as small as possible), and because of it the first way is preferred. The question is what an algorithm should I use to find a such way where a maximum distance of a jump would be minimal?

I have thought about two ways:

1. Brute force, but it will be inconvenient when the number of platform will be `=N*M`;
2. Somehow transfer this matrix into graph where each platform is presented as a node of a graph and edges are presented by a distances of jumps and find a minimal spanning tree but firstly I do not know ho to create a matrix of adjacent in this way and will be this way correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse the map and find nodes:

```
for i from 1 to N
    for j from 1 to M
        if map(i, j) == 'S' 
            nodes.add(i, j);
            start = nodes.Count;
        elseif map(i, j) == 'D' 
            nodes.add(i, j);
            dest = nodes.Count;
        elseif map(i, j) == '_'
            nodes.add(i, j);
        end
    end
end
```

In above pseudocode I assume that `nodes.add(i, j)` adds a new node with `node.x = 1` and `node.y = j` to the list of nodes.

Then, to construct adjacency matrix:

```
n = nodes.Count;
adj = n by n matrix, filled with +inf;
for i from 1 to n
    for j from i + 1 to n
       if (nodes[i].x == nodes[j].x) || (nodes[i].y == nodes[j].y)
           adj(i, j) = abs(nodes[i].x - nodes[j].x) +
               abs(nodes[i].y - nodes[j].y);
       end
    end
end
```

The rest is a [Shortest Path Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem). Use [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find the shortest path between `start` and `dest` nodes.

Comment: I do not need to find the shortest path! I need to find the path that contains a minimal edges!

Comment: @AyratArifullin Sure, but the algorithm is the same. When growing the path and updating the current shortest path you don't need to compare `sum(weights)`, but `max(weights)`.

Comment: @AyratArifullin Beside that, what if there was multiple paths with same value of longest jump? Don't you want to return the shortest one? Or maybe the one with least number of jumps with max length. All these use same algorithm, but with different ways of comparing two paths.

Comment: @AyratArifullin Keep in mind that  Dijkstra's is actually an optimization algorithm and tries to minimize the "cost", and the "length" only comes from the terminology of the well known problem, "The Shortest Path Problem". Now, when the "cost" in your problem is the "Longest Jump", just use your own cost in same algorithm.

Comment: I have little corrected your suggestion and made a solution. You can check it below. Thank you for supporting my idea! You have just pushed me further

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to post above, I have decided to finish the idea and got this code and for test cases that I was given it works fine. So, the idea is:

1. From the given map of platforms it's necessary to create a graph where one node presents one platform (inlcuding start and destination platform) and an edges between nodes are presented as a distance between them;
2. When you formed the graph, your goal is to find minimal spanning tree and find the maximum weight of edge in this tree - this is answer.
   The code is very big and please check it on my github! Pay attention that `1` means platform, `2` means start and `3` is destination:

[Check this github link out!](https://github.com/Ayrtat/codeforces/blob/master/rock_climbing.cpp)